# Redirect A Certain Page if * Does not exist?

Tags: php

I have a `profile.php` page, and when someone views their own profile, it grabs the id of their user and adds `profile.php?UserID=*` (* being the id number of a user). At the moment, there is no legit way to look at others profiles, but you are able to change the id in the url. Problem is, you can go to the profile of a user who doesn't exist and make it will be the default profile page without anything on it. Is there a way to get the id from a page/url and see if it exists or not, and if not, to redirect to a certain page?

```
<?php
    include('./dbnotseen/global.php');
    $profile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($profile);
    $username = $row['username'];

    if (($session_username)) {

    }else {
        ("location: index.php");
    }

    //max per page
    $per_page = 1;

    //get start variable
    $start = $_GET['UserID'];

    //count records
    $record_count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin"));

    //count max pages
    $mac_pages = $record_count / $per_page;

    if (!$start)
        $start = 0;

    //display data
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$start'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
        $id = $row['username']; 
        $picture = $row['picture'];
        $admin = $row['admin'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $twitter = $row['twitter'];
    }
?>
```

That's the main part of the PHP in the profile.php. The rest is just getting a status, description etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the result set of your mysql query is not empty. Doing it with `mysql_` functions would look like so:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$start'");
if (mysql_num_rows($get) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
        // rest of your code
    }
}
else {
    // redirect to another page
    header("Location: otherpage.php");
}
```

This would give you an idea on how you should approach it, but as `@Madara Uchiha` suggested in the comment to your question, you should stop using `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 0):

A couple important things before solving your problem:

- The MySQL_* family of functions [has been deprecated](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and shouldn't be used anymore.
- Your code is vulnerable to a huge security hole - [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please make sure you're sanitizing your database queries - if nothing else, with just `$start = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['UserID']);` in your current code.

Now, it looks like you want to check and see how many results you get back for your `$get` query. You could just use the `mysql_num_rows` function:

```
if (!mysql_num_rows($get)) {
    //no user exists! do something different here
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
        $id = $row['username']; 
        $picture = $row['picture'];
        $admin = $row['admin'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $twitter = $row['twitter'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also count the records in the `admin` table matching criteria `id = $start` with the following SQL statement:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM admin WHERE id='$start'"
```

If there are no matching records, then the provided UserID doesn't belong to any user and you should probably redirect the user to some page explaining what went wrong.